# Error handling in collection environment

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that copies the content of a input table to an output table using the header names stored in a collection. Code:

```
Sub Process_Data()

Dim rawSht As Worksheet
Dim procSht As Worksheet
Dim headers As Collection
Dim c As Integer
Dim v As Variant

Set rawSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend - raw")
Set procSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend - processed")

Set headers = New Collection
For c = 1 To rawSht.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    headers.Add c, rawSht.Cells(4, c).Text
Next

For c = 5 To 50
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    rawCol = headers(procSht.Cells(8, c).Text)
    v = rawSht.Range(rawSht.Cells(5, rawCol), rawSht.Cells(Rows.Count, rawCol).End(xlUp)).Value2
    procSht.Cells(9, c).Resize(UBound(v, 1)).Value = v

ErrorHandler:
    Next

End Sub
```

I now tried to handle the error if I would insert a column in the output table, with a header not contained in the collection of headers from the input table.

My solution with `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` and then `ErrorHandler: Next` works if there is no more than 1 inserted column at a time (e.g. 2 or more inserted columns following each other returns an error). It also does not work if the inserted column is at the beginning or at the end of the output table.

What I would like to do is: If the header is found in the collection, copy & paste the data from input table, if the header is not found in the collection, go to the next header, if the next header is empty, stop the macro.

Comment: You must use a `Resume` statement to clear the error raised.

Comment: @Rory: Do you mean as in `On Error Resume Next`? Because that copies the values of the next input-column in into the inserted column in the output table. Maybe I fail to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
For c = 5 To 50
   rawCol = vbNullString
    On Error Resume Next
    rawCol = headers(procSht.Cells(8, c).Text)
    On Error Goto 0
    if rawcol <> vbnullstring then
v = rawSht.Range(rawSht.Cells(5, rawCol), rawSht.Cells(Rows.Count, rawCol).End(xlUp)).Value2
    procSht.Cells(9, c).Resize(UBound(v, 1)).Value = v
    End If
    Next
```